# How would I handle certain, specific submorphs differently using TableLayout?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, morphic

I have a morph. This morph is designed to hold a row of submorphs, which I use a TableLayout layout policy for and it works well.

However, I want this morph to have a specific submorph that is always positioned directly below the morph. This specific submorph is determined by an instance variable of the morph.

[image]

In this example, the main morph is cyan, and the submorphs are red, green and blue. The purple morph is currently not a submorph of the main morph, but it demonstrates where I want it to be as a submorph.

Let's say that the main morph has the purple morph in one of its instance variables, and the purple morph is also a submorph of the main morph. How would I treat that submorph differently when organizing the morph's contents using TableLayout?

I haven't tried much of anything yet. This is partially because I wouldn't know how to try, and partially because this seems like a common enough use case that there might be a solution better than anything I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the first obvious question would be: Why do you want `purple` to be a submorph of `main`? Grouping morphs based on common properties usually helps organizing and layouting them. In general, it's a widespread practice in Morphic to use composition extensively.

<sub>**Preliminary note:** As you did not provide a code sample, I will work with the following baseline script:</sub>

```
main := Morph new
    color: Color cyan;
    borderWidth: 2;
    borderColor: Color black.
main
    changeTableLayout;
    listDirection: #leftToRight;
    hResizing: #shrinkWrap;
    vResizing: #shrinkWrap;
    cellGap: 5.
main addAllMorphs:
    {Morph new color: Color red; borderWidth: 2; borderColor: Color black.
    Morph new color: Color green; borderWidth: 2; borderColor: Color black.
    Morph new color: Color blue; borderWidth: 2; borderColor: Color black}.
purple := Morph new color: Color magenta.

main openInWorld.

purple openInWorld.
purple topLeft: main bottomLeft.
```

[image: Original situation]

### Solution 1: Composition

If you use composition, you can arrange both `main` and `purple` in another table-layouted transparent container:

```
outer := Morph new
    changeTableLayout;
    beTransparent;
    hResizing: #shrinkWrap;
    vResizing: #shrinkWrap;
    cellPositioning: #topLeft;
    yourself.
outer addAllMorphs: {main. purple}.
outer openInWorld.
```

[image: Solution 1: Composition]

### Solution 2: Exclude single morph from its owner layout policy

Just for sake of completion, it is also possible to exclude a single morph from its owner layout policy as you requested. This can be done by enabling the `#disableLayout` property on the relevant submorph:

```
purple disableLayout: true.
main vResizing: #rigid; height: 44.
main addMorph: purple.
purple topLeft: main bottomLeft.
```

[image: Solution 2: Exclude single morph from its owner layout policy]

However, I would not consider this solution idiomatic in most situations:

1. You are foregoing composition (as described above) which increases the overall layout complexity.
2. You are deliberately positioning a morph outside of the bounds of this owner. While Morphic generally supports this (see `#fullBounds`), this is often unexpected and may make certain inspection and debugging tasks harder. For instance, to invoke a halo on the purple morph in this example, you need to either press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Blue</kbd>, or turn on the preference "Halo encloses full bounds". Note that since Squeak 6.0, you can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Blue</kbd> to override this preference once.